# Run Chrome using IPv6

Tags: windows, google-chrome, centos

In my Windows 11 machine and in my CentOS 9 stream I have 2 IPs assigned: one is IPv4 and another is IPv6. I can use both IPs on these computers and it works fine.

When I use Chrome, by default it uses IPv4 to make all requests (every website I access chrome will use IPv4).

So I ask you: is there any Chrome switch/flag that I can set in order to make it use the IPv6 by default?

I think this is not a case of proxy, right? I already have both IPs available on these computers, I am wondering if there is a command line that I can use to start Chrome and make it use IPv6.

Thanks and marry christians!

Comment: AFAIK chrome doesn't have a built-in option or flag that allows users to force IPv6 usage by default

Comment: @Daqs so is it possible to do inside the operating system (CentOS in my case)?

Comment: The IPv6 IP can only be used for IPv6 traffic. So you need an IPv6 capable internet connection (there are several IPv6 test sites available ) and then browse to an IPv6 enabled web site.